# add picture to more than 1 page of a word file using vb

Tags: vb.net-2010

How can i add an image on more than 1 page of a word file using vb.net? The image should be in the same position for all pages. That is all the detail i can give 
This my code:

```
 For i = 1 To 2
        'Insert a paragraph at the beginning of the document.
        oPara1 = oDoc.Content.Paragrap
        oPara1.Range.Text = "                      AUXILLIUM GIRLS'S HIGHER SECONDARY SCHOOL"
        oPara1.Range.Font.Size = 16
        oPara1.Range.Font.Bold = True
        oPara1.Format.SpaceAfter = 10   '24 pt spacing after paragraph.
        oPara1.Range.InsertParagraphAfter()


        ''Adds a new canvas to the document 
        shpCanvas = oDoc.Shapes _
        .AddCanvas(Left:=250, Top:=topvalue, _
        Width:=75, Height:=75)
        shpCanvasShapes = shpCanvas.CanvasItems

        'Adds shapes to the CanvasShapes collection 
        With shpCanvasShapes
            .AddPicture("D:\logo.jpg", Width:=75, Height:=75)
        End With


        Pos = oWord.InchesToPoints(7)
        oDoc.Bookmarks.Item("\endofdoc").Range.InsertParagraphAfter()
        Do
            oRng = oDoc.Bookmarks.Item("\endofdoc").Range
            oRng.ParagraphFormat.SpaceAfter = 6
            oRng.InsertAfter("A line of text")
            oRng.InsertParagraphAfter()
        Loop While Pos >= oRng.Information(Word.WdInformation.wdVerticalPositionRelativeToPage)
        oRng.Collapse(Word.WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd)
        oRng.InsertBreak(Word.WdBreakType.wdPageBreak)
        oRng.Collapse(Word.WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd)
        oRng.InsertAfter("We're now on page 2. Here's my chart:")
        oRng.InsertParagraphAfter()

        'oWord.Selection.InlineShapes.AddPicture("d:\logo.jpg")
        Thread.Sleep(4000)
    Next i
```